# List of Permutations with repetitions in 2D array

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, permutation, repeat

I have a problem to list permutations with repetitions, maintaining this "style", with recursive functions.

Having for example 2 element, "AB" and "CD", in a 2D array:

```
Element[0][0] = A; Element[0][1] = B; // AB    
Element[1][0] = C; Element[1][1] = D; // CD
```

I want to get all the possible permutations with repetition of n elements (in this case 2) into k groups (in this case 2) and save them to a new 2D array
For example in:

```
Permutation[0][0] = AB; Permutation[0][1] = AB; // 1°: AB,AB
Permutation[1][0] = AB; Permutation[1][1] = CD; // 2°: AB,CD
Permutation[2][0] = CD; Permutation[2][1] = AB; // 3°: CD,AB
Permutation[3][0] = CD; Permutation[3][1] = CD; // 4°: CD,CD
```

Element and Permutation must be a two-dimensional array.
I tried this way but it only works with a permutation of 2 element into 2 groups and I'm locked:

```
    int i_perm = 0;
    int i_element = 0;
    int k_tot = 2; // number of groups

    [...]

    calcPerms(2);

    [...]

    private void calcPerms(int k)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            if(i_perm + 1 < i_perm)
                i_perm++;

            i_element=0;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++)
            {
                Permutation[i_perm][i_element][0] = Element[i][0];
                Permutation[i_perm][i_element][1] = Element[i][1];

                if(i_element + 1 < k_tot)
                    i_element++;

                calcPerms(k - 1);

                if(i_perm >= i_perm)
                    i_perm--;

                Permutation[i_perm][i_element][0] = Element[i][0];
                Permutation[i_perm][i_element][1] = Element[i][1];
                if(i_element + 1 < k_tot)
                    i_element++;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works, as mentioned above, only on permutations of 2 elements in groups of 2, returning correctly:

ABAB, ABCD, CDAB, CDCD.

Indeed if I put 3 elements (the 3rd element is EF), it returns:

ABAB, ABCD, CDEF, EFAB, ABCD, CDEF, EFAB, ABCD, EFEF

Instead of:

ABAB, ABCD, ABEF, CDAB, CDCD, CDEF, EFAB, EFCD, EFEF

How can I get what I want? Thank you all for your help and apologize for my bad English

Comment: Some notes: A) It's "Java" not JAVA. B) The tags for your question identify the language involved, so it's not necessary to put it in the title.

Comment: Sorry! thanks for the advice

Comment: No big deal, just trying to make this question fit in with the site format better.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)

There's a clear pseudo code implementation in the linked wikipedia page.

The non recursive version looks like this

```
procedure generate(n : integer, A : array of any):
    c : array of int

    for i := 0; i < n; i += 1 do
        c[i] := 0
    end for

    output(A)

    i := 0;
    while i < n do
        if  c[i] < i then
            if i is even then
                swap(A[0], A[i])
            else
                swap(A[c[i]], A[i])
            end if
            output(A)
            c[i] += 1
            i := 0
        else
            c[i] := 0
            i += 1
        end if
    end while
```

Comment: Very nice code, but does not help me.
Heap's Algorithm is permutations without repetitions, like:
ABC, BAC, CAB, ACB, BCA, CBA.
I need permutations with repetitions, like:
AAA  AAB  AAC  ABA  ABB  ABC  ACA  ACB  ACC  BAA  [...]